# Generate public interface for a closed source rust library

Tags: rust

I am making a rust library, but it is closed source, and I'm distributing it as a `.a` file. The entire public interface of the library and all publicly accessible structs have a `C` abi, using `#[repr(C)]`, `#[no_mangle]` etc, and a header file generated using [cbindgen](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen), allowing a C/C++ application to use my library.

But how would a rust application use the `.a` file? How would I generate a "header" - like interface for a rust application to use? To build the application do I just link my `.a` using a build.rs script?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for [rlib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html)?

Comment: @sn99 Yep I looked into this before, but apparently its only meant to be used as an intermediary stage inside tools like cargo, and cannot be moved across systems (both rust compiler version locked and system specific). So this would not work for my usecase.

Comment: You can use the `.a` file just like you would use a C library, e.g. call `bindgen` from `build.rs` to re-generate an FFI module from the header file, then link your `.a` to the application.

Comment: @Jmb but the C api is slightly different from the rust api, because I need to convert / accept pointers when called from C, but a rust application would want to pass `Vec` instead of creating and passing a raw pointer... Is there no cleaner solution? (I currently have macros that generate equivalent pointer-style wrappers which are then used from C)

Comment: The Rust API has nonetheless to pass through the C API, isn't it? So use bindgen, and create a wrapper API.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Nope, there is a separate rust and C api. And I still end up with the issues I answered to Jmb above.

Comment: How can you interact with the code not through the C ABI?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman not sure what exactly you mean. But I have functions like this: `pub fn do_something(input: &Vec<u8>) -> (Vec<Response>, Vec<ErrorType>);` and a macro generated equivalent `int ffi_do_something(uint8_t *buffer, size_t buffer_size, Response *messages, size_t messages_size, ErrorType *errors, size_t errors_size)`. And I have tons of functions like these autogenerated. I would prefer a rust application to use the rust interface, because its idiomatic. If I call bindgen, its quite messy for a rust application to use the C api with raw pointers everywhere.

Comment: @t348575 He means, if you distribute your code through a `.a` file, it only has a C ABI. Rust does not have a stable ABI (to my knowledge), so you can't publish binary Rust crates. You have to go through the C interface, even on Rust projects. For more info, read this discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/6kl9dm/submit_a_binary_only_crate/

Comment: @Finomnis ohhhhhh

Comment: @t348575 Although that reddit post is 6 years old, and I think back then `rlib` didn't really exist yet. `rlib` might be what you want instead of `.a`. I haven't touched the subject yet, though, so take my advise with a grain of salt.

Comment: @t348575 [Here](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/backend/libs-and-metadata.html#rlib) is more info about `rlib`, it sounds like this is indeed what you want for your needs. Although the linked page also states that it isn't guaranteed to stay stable over time. The only really "stable" ABI that exists for binary code is the C ABI.

Comment: @Finomnis The OP said they cannot use rlibs as they are not stable across environments.